# When I build my project it takes lots of time to compile

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, cpu-usage

I have a *.Net Standard 2.0* project, when I try to build it using the command line (dotnet CLI) or VS (20017 v15.7.4) it took a long time to compile and CPU usage will rise to upper than 98%.

[image: CPU leak]

Is there any way for me to find out why that process is using too much CPU and where is CPU leak?

Comment: What exactly is "a long time" and why would you want it to use less than 100% of your processor?

Comment: @nvoigt, I'm developing an application and each time I compile the project it will take about 3 min to compile. I hadn't had this issue before. I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: So which step is taking that long? Don't you have output of any kind?

Comment: @nvoigt I have no idea, I just run dotnet build and after long time result is successful.

Comment: Run `dotnet build -v diag` to see what it does.

Comment: Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleaned your application?  it seems your using Visual Studio which should have a Clean solution type button.  I would recommend trying that, as well as restarting your computer to see if it speeds up the compile time.

Otherwise I would set up some timers in your code, and try to investigate which area of your code is making the application compile for an excess amount of time.  Once you discover that you can try to improve the performance of that section.